# Windows culture is emphasizing on my C# calendar, how to force C# calendar to remain in Gregorian format?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I am working on Windows Forms.
I am using calendar control in VS 2010. I want that if i change the culture of my windows to Arabic, the calendar control should remain in Gregorian (english) style. But when i change the language of my windows, my calendar also converts into Hijri calendar, i am trying to find the way to force my calendar to remain in Gregorian format.

Actually its an application in which there are two calendars, and we are selecting Gregorian calendar and getting result in hijri calendar, but when my windows locale is changed to Arabic, my Gregorian calendar also becomes hijri calendar, which disturbs the purpose of this application.

Please tell me what is the solution?

Comment: What happens when you explicitly define the `locale` you want to use for the calendar control?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b889834&x=18&y=19

Comment: I have updated my description. Please check now.

Comment: @stuartd - you're correct; it is windows native control, wrapped in .NET even in .NET 4.0 (just tested); only way around is to 1) write your own control 2) download some existing calendar control 3) force window locale :)